# Modify XML Configuration if Condition is Met - Ansible

Tags: xpath, ansible

Hi I am new to ansible and I have to write a script for deployment where an artifact will be dropped in a folder and it's package is referenced from an XML config file. I am able to do the first part and it works just fine but the second part is challenging me where I have to edit the conf file and add a child element there. It is written like this:

```
- name: Configure Artifact Properties
- xml:
    path: '{{ server_home }}/conf.xml'
    xpath: /Server/SupportedArtifactTypes
    add_children:
      - NewArtifact
          ArtifactName: HelloWorld
          ArtifactPackage: org.HelloWorld
```

Now this will work fine the first time but when I am going to rerun it in the next deployment cycle, its going to add the child element again which should not be happening. Does anybody have a clue how can we modify the task so that the configuration is added only if it does not exist?

Comment: "*its going to add the child element again*" - why?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ansible XML documentation, you can perform a count against xpath matches. Try doing a count of the xpath first and register the result. Make your task execute when the count is less than 1.

```
- name: Check for existing artifacts in SupportedArtifactTypes
- xml:
    path: '{{ server_home }}/conf.xml'
    xpath: /Server/SupportedArtifactTypes
    count: yes
  register: hits  

- name: Configure Artifact Properties
- xml:
    path: '{{ server_home }}/conf.xml'
    xpath: /Server/SupportedArtifactTypes
    add_children:
      - NewArtifact
          ArtifactName: HelloWorld
          ArtifactPackage: org.HelloWorld
  when: hits.count < 1
```

Give this a try and see if it helps!